# Выводит ошибку что у объекта нет текста, хотя он там присутсвует

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Вот код:

```
import requests
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

now = datetime.datetime.now()
now_date = now.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")

URL = 'https://sxodim.com/almaty/search-events?date_from=' + now_date + '&date_to=' + now_date
HEADERS = {'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18363'}
response = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
news_sxodim = soup.find_all('div', class_='news small  ')
title_sxodim = ''
price_sxodim = ''

page_num = []

for i in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'info'):
    price_sxodim += i.find('div', class_ = 'str bold').text.strip() + '\n'

print(price_sxodim)
```

Вот ошибка:

```
`price_sxodim += i.find('div', class_ = 'str bold').text.strip() + '\n'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`
```

А вот откуда я пытаюсь взять нужную мне инфу:

```html
    <a href="https://sxodim.com/almaty/event/klassicheskiy-ekspress-tur-ot-sxodim-travel-13-dekabrya" class="img" style="background-image:url('/uploads/images_cache/341x200/posts/2020/12/03/8c19029adfdaad9609293bcb686acfb2.jpg')">
                                                                <span class="ticket_icon sold_out"></span>
                                        </a>
    <div class="info">
                    <div class="category_wrapper">
                <a href="https://sxodim.com/almaty/events/tourism" class="category">
                    Туризм
                </a>
                <div class="views">326</div>
            </div>
            <div style="width:80%">
        <a class="title" href="https://sxodim.com/almaty/event/klassicheskiy-ekspress-tur-ot-sxodim-travel-13-dekabrya">Классический экспресс-тур от Sxodim Travel (13 декабря)</a>
    </div>

        
        <div class="favorite_btn " data-id="35618" data-show_popup="login">
            <svg class="svg-icon svg-icon--favorite">
                <use xlink:href="https://sxodim.com/app/images/sprite.svg#favorite"></use>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="descr">
            <div class="str">
            13 декабря
        </div>

        
                    <div class="str">300 км от города Алматы, на территории национального парка «Көлсай көлдері»</div>
                            <div class="str bold">8500 - 9500 тенге</div>
                    </div>
    </div>
```

Меня интересуют class "str bold".

Подскажите в чем проблема

Comment: советую прочитать как создать [mcve]

Comment: [что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проблема в том что `div` с классом `str bold` не всегда присутствует. поэтому в ситуациях когда он отсутствует ничего не делать

```
for i in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'info'):
    el = i.find('div', class_ = 'str bold')
    if el:
        price_sxodim += el.text.strip() + "\n"

print(price_sxodim)
```

если надо оставить `None` то так:

```
for i in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'info'):
    el = i.find('div', class_ = 'str bold')
    if el:
        price_sxodim += el.text.strip() + "\n"
    else:
        price_sxodim += "None\n" 
print(price_sxodim)
```

Comment: Лучше так: `if el is not None:` -> `if el:` ;)

Comment: @DamirYessenbek, просто упростил проверку `el`, приведя к общему виду. Да и Danis уже подправил в своем ответе этот момент

Comment: @gil9red, насоколько я понимаю это проверка на пустоту? Если текст отсутсвует, то он его пропускает?

Comment: @DamirYessenbek, в данном случае проверка что не None. Это общая проверка она сгодится чтобы отсеять None, пустые коллекции (списки, множества, словари, кортежи и т.д.) пустые строки, и прочие объекты, что могут проверяться на bool

Comment: @gil9red это понятно, но получается что он будет пропускать None, но мне нужно чтобы None тоже присутсвовал, в том же порядке, что и в HTML коде

Comment: @DamirYessenbek, добавить `else` и там писать что нужно добавить. Вам наверное туда просто перевод на новую строку нужно было :)

Comment: @gil9red, да спасибо, уже сделал